# Definition of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry

I have found it next to impossible to find a **definition** of the hyperbolic plane.  I am aware of all sorts of imperfect models of the hyperbolic plane -- the pseudosphere, the Poincare disc.

I also know several of its characteristics -- multiple "straight" lines through a given point not meeting another straight line not containing the point -- a surface in space of everywhere negative curvature satisfies the above hyperbolic axiom, etc. etc.

I would like a definition of just what the pseudosphere and the Poincare disc are imperfect models **of**.  Wiki, Needham, Climenhaga etc. etc. do *not* provide explicit definitions.  This is very unusual for a mathematical object of such interest.

Comment: I don't know why you say that the models are “imperfect”, but if you prefer an axiomatic definition, have a look at Robin Hartshorne's *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*, section 40.

Comment: Bonola has translations of both Bolyai and Lobachevski http://store.doverpublications.com/0486600270.html

Comment: A closed loop in the plane can be shrunk to a point, but not all loops on the pseudosphere can be.  Also lines can't be extended in all directions on the pseudosphere -- but the reference you gave was quite helpful -- thanks. Also Hilbert showed that even though any plane is two dimensional, 3 dimensional Euclidean geometry can't accommodate a model of the hyperbolic plane (Needham p. 326).

Comment: Your question reminds me of [What's the point of the Poincaré disc model?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1112447/35416) Both you and that author seem to associate the term “model” with the engineering sense of “imperfect approximation” instead of the definition in model theory as a structure satifying a given set of formulas like the axioms of hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Regarding the term *pseudosphere*, note that different people use it to denote different things. While some use it as a synonym for the tractricoid, others use it as a generic term for any hyperbolic surface. See [this anser of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/666101/35416) arguing that this is the meaning Beltrami used, for example. Depending on which definition of the term you use, the model may be imperfect or not.